# Appcelerator: Check if notifications are present in the Notification Tray

Tags: ios, notifications, apple-push-notifications, appcelerator-mobile, system-tray

I have got push notifications working on my iOS application. I am able to receive the push notifications right away when the app is in focus. If the app is in the background, the push notifications get populated in the notification tray.

My issue is this. If I do not click on the notifications in the notification tray, the 'callback' event does not get called even when i get the app in focus.

I would like to know if there is a method in appcelerator which allows me to find if there are notifications related to my app pending in the tray (Something like Silent Notifications). Is there anything that i can use to achieve this?

I have googled and am unable to find a solution for this. Any thoughts or ideas are sincerely appreciated.